# Wrapping a select tag in a div bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-form-helper

How is it possible to do this? I want to use a horizontal form and define their widths with classes such as `col-sm-6` on the div that wraps the input. For some reason select tags do not get this div.

How can i add a div to wrap only the select tag and not its label?

Sorry, was in a rush.

Here is the code that i'm working with:

```
= bootstrap_form_for resource, url: wizard_path, method: :put, html: {class: 'horizontal-form'} do |form|
  = form.select :cover_type, form.object.cover_types, {include_blank: true, label: "Cover Type"}
```

i want the label and the select to be six columns wide. i can achieve this for the label using `label_class: col-sm-6` but i cannot get it to work for the `select`.

i'm using the rails-bootstrap-form gem

Cheers

Comment: It might help if you post the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

Busy day, sorry guys, i knew i knew how to do this.

Here's the answer:

```
 = bootstrap_form_for resource, url: wizard_path, method: :put, layout: :horizontal, label_col: "col-sm-6", control_col: "col-sm-6" do |form|
  = form.select :cover_type, form.object.cover_types, {include_blank: true, label: "Cover Type"}
```

The gem has these exact options.

Cheers